# Is there a way to allow an unknown enum tag when deserializing with Serde?

Tags: enums, rust, serde

I'm deserializing a tagged enum:

```
#[derive(Deserialize)]
enum Foo {
    A(A),
    B(B),
    C(C),
}
```

If Serde encounters a tag that isn't `A`, `B` or `C`, then it will throw an error. Is there any way to add a catch-all variant for unknown tags? I'd be happy if it only records the tag:

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize)]
enum Foo {
    A(A),
    B(B),
    C(C),
    #[serde(unknown_tag)]
    Unknown(String),
}
```

Comment: There's [`#[serde(other)]`](https://serde.rs/variant-attrs.html#other), but it won't record the tag.

Comment: Ah yes, not sure how I missed that, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can use an [untagged enum](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html#untagged) for this. The details depend on what you want to do exactly.  The idea is to wrap `Foo` into a `MaybeFoo`, where `MaybeFoo` has a "universal" type to deserialize into as the second choice.

In the example below, we use a [`serde_json::Value`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/1.0.57/serde_json/enum.Value.html) as a dummy-type, as its implementation of `Deserialize` is universal as can deserialize anything that is valid JSON. If your source format is different, you may need a different deserializer or implement `Deserialize` yourself.

```
#[derive(serde::Deserialize, serde::Serialize, PartialEq, Debug)]
enum Foo {
  A(u64),
  B(f32),
  C(String),
}

// MaybeFoo is untagged, which also means it "looks" exactly
// like a Foo when serialized/deserialized. 
#[derive(serde::Deserialize, PartialEq, Debug)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum MaybeFoo {
    Foo(Foo),
    Other(serde_json::Value)
}
```

The `MaybeFoo` is an "untagged" enum and Serde will try to deserialize `MaybeFoo` as a `Foo` and - if that fails - as `serde_json::Value` which will always succeed (if sourced from JSON).

```
fn main() {
    // Lets create a Foo and serialize it
    let foo = Foo::B(0.0);
    let foo_json = serde_json::to_string(&foo).unwrap();
    println!("{}", &foo_json);

    // Deserialize works as expected
    let foo_json = "{\"B\":0.0}";
    assert!(serde_json::from_str::<Foo>(&foo_json).unwrap() == foo);

    // Deserializing as a `MaybeFoo` works as expected
    assert!(serde_json::from_str::<MaybeFoo>(&foo_json).unwrap() == MaybeFoo::Foo(foo));    

    // Deserializing something else is not a `Foo`!
    let foo_json = "{\"Unknown\":0.0}";
    let foo = serde_json::from_str::<MaybeFoo>(&foo_json).unwrap();

    // Prints "Other(Object({"Unknown": Number(0.0)}))"
    println!("{:?}", &foo);
}
```

You can use serde_json's API to inspect the unknown variant and - if it looks like a map - extract the tag. If this is your only interest, the second variant of `MaybeFoo` could also be a `HashMap<String, serde::de::IgnoredAny>`, which will deserialize any map, record the tag as a `String` and throw away the value. This presumes, however, that the unknown value is a tagged value.

Comment: Thanks! What if I'm not using JSON? Is there some kind of `serde::Value` type? I couldn't seem to find one.

Comment: That depends on the underlying format, someone needs to do the deserialization of the "other"-case and there is no such thing as a "universal" deserializer. If the underlying format is string-based, a `HashMap<String, String>` (or, as above, a `HashMap<String, serde::de::IgnoredAny>` may work.