# How to ignore unknown enum variant while deserializing?

Tags: rust, deserialization, serde

I have several non-exhaustive enums which I need to handle nicely.
When a not yet known variant is detected, I need to simply ignore value and continue processing the others.

I am currently deserializing vectors of data from and I managed to properly obtain vectors of MyStruct for my application.

My application needs to be forward-compatible with new versions of enums and simply ignores unknown variants.

For example, currently:

```
use serde::{Deserialize};

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
#[non_exhaustive]
pub enum CaseStyle {
    Lowercase,
    Uppercase,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
#[non_exhaustive]
pub enum Encoding {
    Plain,
    Base64,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct MyStruct {
    case_style: CaseStyle,
    encoding: Encoding,
}

fn main() {
    let j = r#"[
    {"case_style": "Lowercase","encoding":"Plain"},
    {"case_style": "Snakecase","encoding":"Plain"},
    {"case_style": "Lowercase","encoding":"Aes"},
    {"case_style": "Uppercase","encoding":"Base64"}
    ]"#;

    // Convert the JSON string to vec.
    let deserialized: Vec<MyStruct> = serde_json::from_str(&j).unwrap();

    // Prints deserialized = [MyStruct { case_style: Lowercase, encoding: Plain }, MyStruct { case_style: Uppercase, encoding: Base64 }]
    println!("deserialized = {:?}", deserialized);
}
```

This example fails because of the 2 unknown variant in json data. How could I just ignore these unknown variants from the deserialization?

Comment: What should `encoding` be decoded into when it's unknown ? Don't you want an `Option<Encoding>` instead ?

Comment: [Does this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63560563/is-there-a-way-to-allow-an-unknown-enum-tag-when-deserializing-with-serde/63561656#63561656) answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to allow an unknown enum tag when deserializing with Serde?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63560563/is-there-a-way-to-allow-an-unknown-enum-tag-when-deserializing-with-serde)

Comment: @DenysSéguret That is not the actual code but more of an example of what I need. I can't change the type of `encoding` simply as this would imply checking whether field is Some or None.

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize a `Vec<Option<MyStruct>>` by converting all deserialization errors to `None` and all successes to `Some(...)`. Afterwards, you can remove the `Option` by `flatten`ing them. You could skip the `Option` but this would require you to write a custom deserializer for `Vec`.

Based on the [`serde_with`](https://github.com/jonasbb/serde_with) crate:

```rust
use serde::Deserialize;
use serde_with::{serde_as, DefaultOnError};

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
#[non_exhaustive]
pub enum CaseStyle {
    Lowercase,
    Uppercase,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
#[non_exhaustive]
pub enum Encoding {
    Plain,
    Base64,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct MyStruct {
    case_style: CaseStyle,
    encoding: Encoding,
}

fn main() {
    let j = r#"[
        {"case_style": "Lowercase","encoding":"Plain"},
        {"case_style": "Snakecase","encoding":"Plain"},
        {"case_style": "Lowercase","encoding":"Aes"},
        {"case_style": "Uppercase","encoding":"Base64"}
        ]"#;

    #[serde_as]
    #[derive(Deserialize)]
    struct W(#[serde_as(as = "Vec<DefaultOnError>")] Vec<Option<MyStruct>>);

    // Convert the JSON string to vec.
    let deserialized: Vec<MyStruct> = serde_json::from_str::<W>(&j)
        .unwrap()
        .0
        .into_iter()
        .flatten()
        .collect();

    // Prints deserialized = [MyStruct { case_style: Lowercase, encoding: Plain }, MyStruct { case_style: Uppercase, encoding: Base64 }]
    println!("deserialized = {:?}", deserialized);
}
```

Comment: I was thinking of something like this but the actual serialized structure is buried in a more complex struct. Anyway, it seems something like this could be implemented in a DeserializeSeed like indicated [here](https://serde.rs/ignored-any.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Deserializer};
use serde_with::{serde_as, DefaultOnError};

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
#[non_exhaustive]
pub enum CaseStyle {
    Lowercase,
    Uppercase,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
#[non_exhaustive]
pub enum Encoding {
    Plain,
    Base64,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct MyStruct {
    case_style: CaseStyle,
    encoding: Encoding,
}


#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct VecMyStruct {
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "skip_on_error")]
    items: Vec<MyStruct>,
}
fn skip_on_error<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Vec<MyStruct>, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    #[serde_as]
    #[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
    struct MayBeT(#[serde_as(as = "DefaultOnError")] Option<MyStruct>);

    let values: Vec<MayBeT> = Deserialize::deserialize(deserializer)?;

    Ok(values.into_iter().filter_map(|t| t.0).collect())
}

fn main() {
    let j = r#"{"items":[
    {"case_style": "Lowercase","encoding":"Plain"},
    {"case_style": "Snakecase","encoding":"Plain"},
    {"case_style": "Lowercase","encoding":"Aes"},
    {"case_style": "Uppercase","encoding":"Base64"}
    ]}"#;

    // Convert the JSON string to vec.
    let deserialized: VecMyStruct = serde_json::from_str(&j).unwrap();

    // Prints deserialized = VecMyStruct { items: [MyStruct { case_style: Lowercase, encoding: Plain }, MyStruct { case_style: Uppercase, encoding: Base64 }] }
    println!("deserialized = {:?}", deserialized);
}
```

I found this way of doing thanks to @jonasbb. The only issue that I now have is to have a more generic "skip_on_error" method, that could take any `T: Deserialize<'de>` and not only `MyStruct`. As soon as I add `T` type, compiler tells me errors  while implementing `Deserialization` for `MaybeT`.